# Starting point to maintain a website (Test and production enviroment ) with git

Tags: git

Here is the architecture of my project:
[image]

2 different web servers, one for production environment and other one for test environment ( It contents developer1 folder and developer2 folder).

My question is : Using git how can configure it in order to :

case 1 :

- Developer 1 can create branch "developer1.b1" based on master on
  production side.
- He works on it then he merges it to origin/developer1.b1 ,
- and he can see his changes in developer1.testServerDomain.com

case 2 :

- Developers can push threir branch to origin master
- then they can see theirs changes in productionServerDomain.com

Comment: You are really asking about several things here.  One is Git workflow strategy, and the other is deployment strategy.  How you deploy doesn't necessarily have anything to do with how you manage your branches. (nog my downvote)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I'm not asking about Git workflow strategy, I wanna just understand how can see update in testDomaine when I change dev.branch and see update in productionDomain when I change master branch, should I need to write a script for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tim has said in comments, you are talking about 2 totally different things.

**deployment**

I would not use GIT to deploy to production.  GIT makes mistakes (a lot).  Branches should be merged and tested first, then a codeball replacement done for deployment.

Dont even have GIT installed on the production server.

**git workflow**

As many devs as you like can then work with the GIT repository, using whatever branches they like.

At release time, build a release branch (or use master as your current release branch), fully test it, then build a deployment package and put it on the server.

There are lots of schools of thought on both of these subjects and everyones solution will be dependent on their development team configuration and server stack/business needs.